# AppAttest -- Can a Swift program that uses DCAppAttestService be run on Linux?

Tags: macos, osx-server, server.app, certificate

I need to be able to run the code that issues an Apple **attest** but not on Apple OS -- on Linux. Or, at the very least, on a MacOS **VPS** -- not a **physical** device.

```
import DCAppAttest

func generateKeyAndAttestation() {
    guard let attestationKey = DCAppAttestService.shared.generateKey() else {
        print("Error generating attestation key.")
        return
    }

    // Generate a nonce (you may need to use a more secure source for your actual use case)
    let nonce = Data.random(count: 32)

    // Prepare the data to be attested
    let dataToAttest = "Data to be attested".data(using: .utf8)!

    // Concatenate nonce and data
    var attestationData = nonce
    attestationData.append(dataToAttest)

    // Use DCAppAttestService to attest the data
    guard let attestation = DCAppAttestService.shared.attestData(attestationData, withKey: attestationKey) else {
        print("Error generating attestation.")
        return
    }

    // Print or use the attestation key and the resulting attestation
    print("Attestation Key: \(attestationKey)")
    print("Attestation: \(attestation)")
}
```

I expect there to be new customers daily, therefore this code will be run regularly. Therefore, using an Apple **physical device** for this, if indeed required, will be inconvenient.

1. I haven't found a clear answer as to whether or not `DCAppAttestService` must be run **only on** MacOS/iOS .
2. And whether or not it has to be a **physical** Apple device or will any VPS running one of the latest OSX do too?

[image]

I'm aware that validation, verification of **attest-s** can, indeed, be run on Linux. This will the 2nd step. My question, however, about the code that issues, generates **attest-s** initially -- the 1st step.

---

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/dcappattestservice

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. I’m going to put a hold on these as they seem to be very code level development related. I’ll check with another moderator to see if we feel it can be migrated directly to stack overflow… stand by while I see if any are available

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate of the other question (you seem to have asked three) that’s already migrated to stack overflow. If they reject the migration please flag for a moderator to assist here.

Comment: @bmike How am I supposed to make comments there, or add clarifications?

Comment: Editing and flagging here is the best path for Ask Different help. I think your best shot at a proper answer is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77776176/

Comment: @bmike How am I supposed to make comments **there**, or add clarifications?

Comment: Forgive me I misunderstood your question - You will want to sign in to the Stack Overflow and establish an account there. It's easiest to use the same credentials as you used here. https://stackoverflow.com Your profile will be linked between both sites as long as you use the same email / or link them after https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts has more details